# Python request not showing desired result

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am not an expert with python but this is what I did with python-requests. I am trying to call this URL that gives me the email id of the user if I provide the first_name, last_name and domain.

https://dry-tor-58240.herokuapp.com

However, when I try to request it with python I get the 200 response code but when I convert the response.text to Beautiful Soup object I don't see the email address anywhere in it.

```
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
payload = {"first_name":"nandish","last_name":"ajani","domain":"atyantik.com"}
r = requests.get("https://dry-tor-58240.herokuapp.com/", headers = headers, params = payload)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
```

Can anyone let me know what is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It should be POST request method. This will return a json format, so I also utilized request's `.json()`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request_url = 'https://dry-tor-58240.herokuapp.com/find'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {"first_name":"nandish","last_name":"ajani","domain":"atyantik.com"}
jsonObj = requests.post(request_url, headers = headers, json = payload).json()
```

**Output:**

```
print (jsonObj['email'])
```